# "Начало" и "Конец"

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Слышала, что слова "начало" и "конец" однокоренные. Но как такое может быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да запросто. 
Очень кратко. НА - в "начале" приставка (сравните - зачин, почин), а К вполне закономерно переходит в Ч и наоборот. В современном языке это осталось рудиментарно: корневое К перед суффиксальными И и Е переходит в Ч, раньше это было в некоторых других ситуациях.

Comment: Коли вопрос подняли, уточню "во избежание", что речь идет о родственности слов на очень древнем, праслявянском, если не индоевропейском уровне. В современном языке слова считать однокоренными нет никаких резонов.

Answer (score 0):

Семит.  АД  КАН  - от и до. на том конец. Начало --  от сходного ЧаТь ( ( желать притягивать  -- ЯТь ) и производные - заЧ-Ть поЧ-Ть наЧаТь ). От  ЯТь  идет  ЯсТь  йисТЬ(вкушать) и нЯТЬ ( брать ) хотя  брать это уже семит. корень (БР)- начало .

Answer (score -1):

начало-> начать (по аналогии с мыть - мыло, рыть - рыло) -> начинать -> чин (корень) 
конец -> кон (корень), ец (старославянский уменьшительно-ласкательный суффикс, аналогия русскому ок: канатоходец - ходок; тунеядец - едок; венец - венок; трезубец - зубок; сучец - сучок)
кон -> чин
о -> и (пример: нарок -> нарицать)
к -> ч (пример: кудесник -> чудесник)